# BigQuery ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT) splitting values basing on column value

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table like this:

```
+------+------------+----------+-------+--------+
| Name |    Date    | Category | Value | Number |
+------+------------+----------+-------+--------+
| John | 2019-01-03 | Cat1     | AA    |     10 |
| John | 2019-01-03 | Cat1     | AB    |     11 |
| John | 2019-01-03 | Cat2     | NN    |     12 |
| John | 2019-01-03 | Cat2     | MM    |     13 |
+------+------------+----------+-------+--------+
```

The first 2 columns are the key identifier and I need to ARRAY/GROUP the rows basing on those 2 columns.

Here is the sample statement:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT "John" name, DATE("2019-01-03") date, "cat1" category, "AA" value, 10 number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "John", DATE("2019-01-03"), "cat1", "AB", 11
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "John", DATE("2019-01-03"), "cat2", "NN", 12
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "John", DATE("2019-01-03"), "cat2", "MM", 13
)

SELECT * FROM data
```

The basic version of the query is very simple:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  date,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT<category STRING, value STRING, number INT64>(category,value,number)
  ) AS items

FROM data
GROUP BY 1,2
```

but in my case I need to distinct the values (on 2 different columns) the `value`-`number` grouped values based on `category` column

I don't know if a dynamic column definition can be made, basing on the DISTINCT values of the `category` values, but in a simplier case I can use fixed values `cat1` and `cat2`

Here an example of the output I described:

```
+------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| Name |    Date    | cat1_grouped.value | cat1_grouped.number | cat2_grouped.value | cat2_grouped.number |
+------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| John | 2019-01-03 | AA                 |                  10 | NN                 |                  12 |
|      |            | AB                 |                  11 | MM                 |                  13 |
|      |            |                    |                     |                    |                     |
+------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is working example - for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'John' name, DATE '2019-01-03' dt, 'Cat1' category, 'AA' value, 10 number UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', '2019-01-03', 'Cat1', 'AB', 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', '2019-01-03', 'Cat2', 'NN', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', '2019-01-03', 'Cat2', 'MM', 13 
)
SELECT name, dt,
  ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(IF(category = 'Cat1', arr, [])) cat1_grouped,
  ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(IF(category = 'Cat2', arr, [])) cat2_grouped
FROM (
  SELECT name, dt, category,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<value STRING, number INT64>(value, number)) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY name, dt, category
)
GROUP BY name, dt
```

with result

```
Row name    dt          cat1_grouped.value  cat1_grouped.number cat2_grouped.value  cat2_grouped.number  
1   John    2019-01-03  AA                  10                  NN                  12    
                        AB                  11                  MM                  13
```

Comment: I did not know about `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG`. Thanks